# How to measure the user experience?

Tags: usability-study

recently I had the joy to be part of a new department in our company,  the user experience department.

I'm really happy with my new work,but recently my bosses started to do some changes in our offices, this include new ways to measure the work of every department, including user experience.

They are asking us at least  5 types of metrics to measure our job. The problem I'm having is how I can created metrics to measure the user experience or his satisfaction?

The best I could find here was "n% of the users accomplished the task in less that n minutes" but I really can't figure it other ways to do it.

Comment: A question that might be useful/related: http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/16891/empirical-measures-of-performance

Comment: See my answer [here.](http://ux.stackexchange.com/a/23398/15829) It's related to the HEART metrics, testing and customer support.

Comment: I suggest updating the resume. Once companies get into the literal/specific numbers game with UX, UX usually loses. (and, in turn, so does the company)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The role of the UX department is to help software projects meet their goals by manipulating user behaviour. Therefore, the way to measure the department's success is to find metrics related to usability that directly reflect on the project's aims. This might seem a trivial observation, but it's vital that you measure success in terms your stakeholders care about.

So, if your company relies on e-commerce, you metrics could be % conversion, % repeat visits, amount-per-unit support required on orders, or any other relevant behavioural metrics. If your strategy requires social media exposure, your metrics will relate to the number of users who share links, the number of shae-ees (as it were) who convert, etc. etc. Deciding what your metrics are involves sitting down with the PM and teasing out the *behaviours* that are critical to success.

A word of warning: there are elements of your strategy that are difficult, no - impossible to quantify with simple analytics. Things like brand strength, trust, goodwill and pleasure cannot be measured by a server. Even surveys and qualitative research are pretty unreliable in this regard. That doesn't mean you should avoid these metrics, but it does mean you might need to communicate the limitations of measurement.

Answer (score 1):

I think that the key metrics below are indicators of good/bad user experience. So, by measuring them you'll have a clue as to the user experience you deliver, but you won't understand the reasons for that. I came across a great article suggesting an interesting approach to improve the UX by using a visual analytics. If you're interested, take a look at: http://www.appsee.com/blog/mobile-ux/improving-user-experience-via-in-app-analytics

In any case, here are the key metrics you can measure:

- User engagement
- User retention/User churn
- Conversion rates
- ARPU (average revenue per user)
- New users vs. returning users
- Bounce rate & high exit pages